# Reading data from usb raspberry pi(headless mode)

Tags: c#, windows, iot, datareader, serial-communication

I am trying read data from USB device using data reader object.
The code is

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {

        deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        await config();
        await WriteAsync();
        while(true)
        await ReadAsync()
        deferral.Complete();

    }
async Task config()
{
  ....
}
 async Task WriteAsync()
{
  ....
}

 async Task ReadAsync()
{
  try
        {

            dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);

            var bytesRead = await dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(1);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                string a = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead).Trim();
                byte[] pass_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a);
                Debug.WriteLine(pass_byte[0]);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("exception in read async", e);
        }

}
```

I was able to get data as intended but for a little amount of time after that, It throws an exception.
It shows exceptions like`arguments out of range exception and SEHE exception`

Comment: '    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=-2147023783
  Message=No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

  Source=""
  StackTrace:
       at Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.ReadString(UInt32 codeUnitCount)
       at gridbackground.StartupTask.<ReadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
  InnerException:'

Comment: The above were the exceptions from the line                                       `string a=dataReaderObject.ReadString.ASCII.GetBytes(a);`

Comment: Looks like your have a encoding problem. Did you try using ReadBytes instead of ReadString?

Comment: Thank you Jackie That fixed the problem